# R: weird behaviour in linear regression

Tags: r, regression, predictive-models, linear-model

I am trying to practice with R through some problems, one of them says:

```
Through a linear regression model WITH APPROPRIATE SCALE CHANGE
based on the campione data, predict the adv number for a duration in seconds equal to the 
average of seconds in PUBB NOT censored
```

Note: CENSORED means that seconds == 60

**code:**

```
##### just to show how the data was set #######
PUBB = read.table('avvisi.txt', header=T)
I1 = sample(which(PUBB$secondi == 60), 0.25*nrow(PUBB))
I2 = sample(which(PUBB$secondi < 60), 0.75*nrow(PUBB), replace = T)
campione = PUBB[c(I1,I2),]
##############################################

x = campione$secondi
y = campione$adv
plot(x, sqrt(y), ylab = "y = adv", xlab = "x = secondi")
model = lm(x~sqrt(y))
summary(model)  # R-squared:  0.9667

argomento = mean(PUBB[which(PUBB$secondi < 60),]$secondi)
predict(model, data.frame(x = argomento))
```

Now I'm getting a lot of results (instead of one as expected) with a warning message:
"Warning message:
'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 640 rows"

To have an idea of the data frame PUBB:

```
> summary(PUBB)
      adv           secondi        
 Min.   :1.000   Min.   : 0.08013  
 1st Qu.:1.000   1st Qu.:16.84150  
 Median :5.000   Median :40.82163  
 Mean   :5.087   Mean   :37.59638  
 3rd Qu.:9.000   3rd Qu.:60.00000  
 Max.   :9.000   Max.   :60.00000  
> str(PUBB)
'data.frame':   1000 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ adv    : int  9 1 1 9 9 9 4 1 9 9 ...
 $ secondi: num  60 12.503 0.821 60 60 ...
> dput(campione, file="campione.txt")
```

see [here (dput of campione)](https://pastebin.com/91NAuT3z)

['avvisi.txt'](https://anonfiles.com/04j3Ff72y3/avvisi_txt)
[my full code](https://pastebin.com/Yg8e8kn2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are having this issue is because the name of your predicted variable from the original regression and the name of your predicted variable in the new data frame don't match. You can try making your variables into objects if you want to name them by `x`. An example with the `iris` dataset in R:

```
#### Predict by Objects ####
data(iris)
y <- iris$Petal.Length
x <- iris$Sepal.Length
fit <- lm(y ~ x)
predict(fit,
        data.frame(x=mean(iris$Sepal.Length)))
```

Which gives you your predicted value:

```
   1 
3.758
```

## EDIT

I've refit the regression using your new `dput` and it seems to still work fine.

```
y <- campione$adv
x <- campione$secondi
fit <- lm(y ~ x)
predict(fit,
        data.frame(x=mean(campione$secondi)))
```

Giving me this

```
    1 
4.428
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I had renamed $$campione$secondi$$ to 'x' and $$campione$adv$$ to 'y'. do you mean this? If so I have already done it, I even tried to pass the mean() function directly instead of the variable  'argument' but nothing changes unfortunately

Comment: You used `predict(fit, data.frame(x=mean(camione$adv)))` after saving `adv` as `x` and running the regression with the saved x?

Comment: May also be helpful if you share the `dput` of your data so people can troubleshoot it.

Comment: I saved campione$adv as y while campione$secondi as x, by the way I re-runned all the commands

Comment: Ok, give me a moment to see how it works, I've never used dput ()

Comment: Basically just save your data as an object (I assume now it is saved already as `camione`, then pass that into `dput` as `dput(camione)`. It should spit out some structure you can copy and paste into your question. Make sure to format it as a code block so people can read it as well.

Comment: Ok ,I did it :)

Comment: I edited my answer. It seems to work on my end.

Comment: I think I see the issue now. Your x and y look to be in the wrong places. Your y should be the first part of the formula.

Comment: So I need to swap x and y?

Comment: Yeah your regression should look like `lm(y ~ x)`, not the other way around. Everything to the right of the tilda sign is a predictor.

Comment: OMG. You are right! I'm feeling very stupid now XD, thank you by the way!

Comment: Haha no problem. Make sure to upvote my answer if you find it useful.

Comment: I tried but I don't have enough 'reputation score' to do it

Comment: Ah that's ok. Thanks anyway for accepting and good luck with your stats!

Comment: Thank you!!! :)